# Methods on JsonSerializable classes causing error

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

When I add the getter `color` below, it doesn't create `fromJson` method anymore. I get this error when I run my app:

> Error: Method not found: 'Alert.fromJson'.

How come? I thought `@JsonKey(ignore: true)` would ignore it? Can I not put methods on JsonSerialzable classes?

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:new_day_flutter/domain/entity/alert/alert_enum.dart';
import 'package:new_day_flutter/domain/entity/alert/alert_severity.dart';
import 'package:new_day_flutter/presentation/theme/palette.dart';

part 'alert.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(constructor: '_', createFactory: true)
class Alert extends Equatable {
  final AlertEnum alert;
  final DateTime time;
  final AlertSeverityEnum severity;

  const Alert._(
      {required this.alert, required this.time, required this.severity});

  factory Alert.highAlarm({required DateTime time}) {
    return Alert._(
        alert: AlertEnum.highAlarm,
        time: time,
        severity: AlertSeverityEnum.medium);
  }

  factory Alert.lowAlarm({required DateTime time}) {
    return Alert._(
        alert: AlertEnum.lowAlarm,
        time: time,
        severity: AlertSeverityEnum.medium);
  }

  factory Alert.lockout({required DateTime time}) {
    return Alert._(
        alert: AlertEnum.lockout, time: time, severity: AlertSeverityEnum.high);
  }

  factory Alert.solutionLow({required DateTime time}) {
    return Alert._(
        alert: AlertEnum.solutionLow,
        time: time,
        severity: AlertSeverityEnum.low);
  }

  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  Color get color {
    if (severity == AlertSeverityEnum.high) {
      return errorRed;
    }
    if (severity == AlertSeverityEnum.medium) {
      return warningOrange;
    }
    if (severity == AlertSeverityEnum.low) {
      return bluelabBlue;
    }

    return bluelabBlue;
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [alert, time, severity];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AlertToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Is `_$AlertFromJson` created?

Comment: @Nitrodon Yep it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_serializable will generate an implementation of fromJson, but it can't add a factory or static method to your class.  You'll have to create the factory yourself (and let the generated implementation do all the real work):

```dart
  factory Alert.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AlertFromJson(json);
```

You may have accidentally deleted that code somehow when you added the `color` getter.

Comment: Thanks! That made it work.